# Apache2 ProxyPass and Redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, reverse-proxy

**Premise:**

I have a custom webserver running on port 2480. I don't really know how it works, but it has it's own www dir. Inside this dir, there is an index.htm file which is executed by default. Inside that file, there is

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/studio/index.html">
```

So, I immediately get redirection to 107.0.0.1:2480/studio/index.html. However, I can't find such "studio" folder anywhere in my filesystem (I have no idea how this works).

**Question:**

In the same server, I have an Apache webserver running on port 80. I'd like to configure a reverse proxy so that "127.0.0.1:80/foo" is equal to "127.0.0.1:2480".

I did in apache2.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
ProxyPass /foo http://localhost:2480/
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://localhost:2480/
```

Then, I navigate to "127.0.0.1:80/foo". I see that it correctly connects to "127.0.0.1:2480/index.htm". But then, index.htm immediately redirects to "/studio/index.html", and I see the url changes to "127.0.0.1:80/studio/index.html. I get then "403 forbidden". But this is a "fake forbidden", because doing this it is just looking for "/studio/index.html" in the default apache document root dir, which of course does not exists (and htaccess is configured to deny all by default).

So question is:

- "127.0.0.1:80/foo" resolves correctly to "127.0.0.1:2480/index.htm"
- "index.htm" redirects to "/studio/index.html"
- **why is apache looking for "127.0.0.1:80/studio/index.html" instead of "127.0.0.1:2480/studio/index.html" ?**

How should this be done?
Thanks a lot

Comment: It's looking for `127.0.0.1:80/studio/index.html` because port 80 is default for http. a Meta-Refresh is just doing a redirection. It doesn't know you want it on port 2480 and you can't specify a port. You need to redirect using another method.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't modify the configuration on the server running on port 2480...